# Bluetooth/USB connection fails after unplugging my laptop

Tags: usb, bluetooth, power-management, ubuntu-mate, bug-reporting

I'm using ubuntu mate 22.10 on AMD ryzen 5 chip set(Vivobook 14). The problem is what is when I disconnect the power plug The Bluetooth disconnects and only connects after restarting. In the case of USB connection also if I unplug my device the connection is loosing and it fixes after restarting the system. Suppose if i'm using Bluetooth/USB connection without plugging the device it working properly until the connected plug disconnects... Anyone knows a solution for this interesting creepy nature of my ubuntu mate desktop? Thanks in advance :)